# Rails Convert JSON String To Javascript Date()

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, json, date

I'm returning some json from one of my controllers similar to the following:

```
render :json => {
:date => "new Date(new Date('Jan 01 2000').getTime() + #{500.seconds.to_i} * 1000)"
}
```

I'm expecting it to return a new date set to 500 seconds past midnight (or exactly 00:08:20). This json gets passed and processed by a JavaScript function that's expecting a date, however it seems to be interpreting it as a string.. I get an error message similar to:

> Type mismatch. Value new Date(new Date('Jan 01 2000').getTime() + 500
>   * 1000) does not match type date

Running that in the Firebug console produces a perfectly valid date, however. How can I get JavaScript to inerpet my json as a date?

---

**Edit**

To provide a little more context I'm sending a series of JSON requests to a JavaScript function that build charts using Google's Visualization API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON is not Javascript](http://www.json.org/), it is just a data serialization format, much like XML.

What you have is actually a string of Javascript code that you need to interpret (or avoid having to interpret, preferably). The only way for that to be valid JSON is, indeed, for it to be a string value. Even then, it should not parse correctly without being inside an array or an object property.

You should refactor whatever's returning that Javascript code to instead return just `'Jan 01 2000'`, and then do that processing in Ruby. Or however it would be best refactored; it's hard to tell without more context.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, so basically I need to move `new Date(new Date('Jan 01 2000').getTime() + milliseconds)` to my JavaScript function? The reason I wanted to do it server-side is because I'm trying to build an agnostic wrapper function for Google's Visualization API, but I guess I'll have to do some additional refactoring if json doesn't interpret JavaScript.

Comment: Handling the date parsing in the JavaScript seems to have done the trick.